# HipHop vs APC vs Other or php optcode caching

Tags: php, caching, apc, hiphop

I've been using APC for a while for just optcode cache and memcached for object caching. I'm thinking of switching from APC to HopHop.

However, it seems that HipHop hasn't had much development lately.   Would anyone recommend using HopHop over APC or just stick with APC?

Thanks!

Comment: unless you serve half of the planet, APC is the right choice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I'd stick with APC.

HipHop is really only for a certain kind of optimization and, from what I've ready, is a pain in the ass to even get your code working with. It doesn't just seamlessly take what you have and convert it. It's my understanding that there's some PHP that can't be used with it.